# Calculating destination point using sf package

Tags: r, coordinates, sf

I have the following data:

```r
lat <- c(-1.404361, -1.403221,-1.387369)
long <- c(35.35373, 35.35047,35.35171 )
distance <- c(220,150,300)
bearing <- c(67,27,159)

df <- data.frame(lat,long,distance,bearing)
```

I transform and project into an `sf` object as follows:

```r
df %>% st_as_sf(coords=c("long", "lat")) %>% st_set_crs(4326) -> df
```

My question is, how do I calculate the destination point for each long/lat origin coordinate, given the distance and bearing? I have used the `destPoint` in the `Geosphere` package, but I cannot find the equivalent in `sf`.

Answer (score 2):

Answer as follows:

```r
library(geosphere)
df_sp <- as_Spatial(df)
destPoint(df_sp, df_sp$distance, df_sp$bearing) %>%
   as.data.frame() %>%
   st_as_sf(coords = c('lon', 'lat')) -> df_sf
```

Comment: You should add `library(geosphere)` (lower case, not `Geosphere` as in the question).

Comment: You can also bypass the `as_Spatial` conversion with `st_coordinates`: `destPoint(st_coordinates(df), df$distance, df$bearing)` - `destPoint` - the first thing `destPoint` does to an `sp` object is create a 2-column matrix.